# Rails asset pipeline on staging: correct fingerprint but 404ing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, production, staging, sprockets

I'm running Rails 3.1.3, which includes Sprockets 2.0.3 as a dependency.

I set up my staging environment to be configured the way the Rails guide suggests for production.

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

I have included in my Capfile

```
load 'deploy'
load 'deploy/assets'
```

And assets get precompiled as expected on deploy.

In public/assets, I find the assets as expected with fingerprints.

```
application-bd402855d34fb61e0a1690da06f79f20.js
application-bd402855d34fb61e0a1690da06f79f20.js.gz
application-ed3f9a8d23992790841c11b6692fb576.css
application-ed3f9a8d23992790841c11b6692fb576.css.gz
...and a bunch of images...
```

When I load the page, I see the correct references, fingerprint and all.

```
<link href="/assets/application-ed3f9a8d23992790841c11b6692fb576.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="/assets/application-bd402855d34fb61e0a1690da06f79f20.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, everything 404s, css, js, images, everything.

Anyone know what the deal is here?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you running staging as 'production' or do you have a staging.rb config file? If so, you may not have the correct pipeline options in there.

Comment: Staging is set up with the config options above, which is the same as what the Rails guide suggests for production. I want pretty much the same behavior. Is that not right?

Comment: It should be fine. I will think about this some more...

Comment: I have the same issue in production mode. Tested locally with exactly same version of rails ruby and sprocket.

Comment: Have you tried doing a rake assets:clean before your precompile? Your staging environment should be identical to your production environment, as this is the whole point of staging.

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437452/rails-3-2-asset-pipeline-with-thin-and-apache-not-finding-assets/9457748#9457748

Comment: Does your application run at a subdirectory?

Comment: Did you configured your Web server (e.g. Nginx) to serve your static assets ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain the assets are being compiled and exist in the public directory, could it be your web server settings? On production/staging environments the assets shouldn't hit the rails app and be served directly from the web server.  Heres an example apache config snippet:

```
   <LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$">
      Header unset ETag
      FileETag None
      # RFC says only cache for 1 year
      ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

      SetEnv no-gzip
      RewriteEngine on
      # Make sure the browser supports gzip encoding before we send it
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} \b(x-)?gzip\b
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -s
      RewriteRule ^(.+) $1.gz [L]

   </LocationMatch>

   <FilesMatch \.css\.gz$>
      ForceType text/css
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
   </FilesMatch>

   <FilesMatch \.js\.gz$>
      ForceType text/javascript
      Header set Content-Encoding gzip
   </FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite suggestions in other answers

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

...is a workaround, not a solution.  This option enables Rails to fall back to on-the-fly compilation of assets that can't be found in public/assets.  It may 'solve' your problem in staging but having Rails compile assets at run-time is not exactly optimal in production.

I remember in the early months of working with the new asset pipeline in Rails 3.1.x that I had problems with both compression and generation of digests that I only really solved in later versions.  I'd suggest trying out

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.digest = false
```

both individually and together.  And/or upgrade to later versions of Rails or the asset pipeline gems.

Answer (score -1):

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

Should be:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Also, make sure clear your cache:

```
bundle exec rake tmp:cache:clear
```

and restart the server.

Answer (score -1):

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

It should be true

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same issue a few months ago.  For a few reasons I chose to go with manually triggering the asset compilation in production so my production.rb has

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

and by capistrano deployment also has a task to precompile the assets (using rvm as well):

```
run "cd #{release_path} && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile", shell: fetch(:rvm_shell)
```

The ultimate step was making sure that we symlinked the assets folder so that we don't need to recompile assets that have not changed.

```
run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/assets #{release_path}/public/assets"
```